# Is there a way to return Sucessful and Failed Queries with a REGEXP in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to Return Both Successful and failed Queries. Right now i'm using REGEXP to look up multiple Values in the Table. However it only returns the Successful Values and doesn't return the Failed ones. Basically I Need to find a way where REGEXP will spit out The Good values along with the invalid value that was not find able.

Comment: the whole point of a regex is to only return things which match the regular expression.

Comment: If you include the successful and the failed queries then you are returning **all** the data and there is no point having the condition at all.

Comment: For what i'm doing it requires to return the failed queries, otherwise the user will not know what queries failed and perhaps need to review the input or notifies the user that the Specific Query doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  str,
        str REGEXP '...'
    FROM tbl;
```

This will return `str` from each row, together with a 1 (for success) or 0 (for failure).  With a suitable `IF` or `CASE`, you turn that 1/0 into some text:

```
SELECT  province,
        IF(province REGEXP 'a', 'Yes', 'No') AS 'contains A'
    FROM  provinces;

+---------------------------+------------+
| province                  | contains A |
+---------------------------+------------+
| Alberta                   | Yes        |
| British Columbia          | Yes        |
| Manitoba                  | Yes        |
| New Brunswick             | No         |
| Newfoundland and Labrador | Yes        |
| Northwest Territories     | No         |
| Nova Scotia               | Yes        |
| Nunavut                   | Yes        |
| Ontario                   | Yes        |
| Prince Edward Island      | Yes        |
| Quebec                    | No         |
| Saskatchewan              | Yes        |
| Yukon                     | No         |
+---------------------------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(To the Commenters, note how this has turned into a "lesson" on REGEXP.)

Comment: This Pulls up all the Data in my Table, I just want it to be where whatever the user inputs into a field it only returns Yes and No to that specific search. 


     `code

     SELECT invoice_no 
     from invoices 
     where invoice REGEXP('Var 1'|'Var2') && 
     AMOUNT IN ( 335.39,202 ) && Status = 2
     `
 i just want it to return Which Expressions were not True and which Expressions were True

Var 1 = YES
var 2 = NO

Comment: @Shredderx - I'm lost.  Please edit your Question to provide a brief example of the data and the desired output.